# how can I find percentage of similar string within and across various columns

Tags: r

I have a data like below

```
df<-structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c("CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR", "DLNYCFSGMSDHR", "FPEHELIVDPQR", 
"IADPDAVKPDDWDEDAPSK", "LWADHGVQACFGR", "WGEAGAEYVVESTGVFTTMEK", 
"YYVTIIDAPGHR"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 
7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR", 
"GCITIIGGGDTATCCAK", "HVGPGVLSMANAGPNTNGSQFFICTIK", "LLELGPKPEVAQQTR", 
"MVCCSAWSEDHPICNLFTCGFDR", "YYVTIIDAPGHR"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "AVCMLSNTTAIAEAWAR", "DLNYCFSGMSDHR", "FPEHELIVDPQR"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want to know which and how many of the strings are shared in each column

for example

```
CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR          1,2       
YYVTIIDAPGHR               1,2
WGEAGAEYVVESTGVFTTMEK      1,1
FPEHELIVDPQR               1,3
DLNYCFSGMSDHR              1,3
DLNYCFSGMSDHR              1,3
```

It means the first string `CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR` is repeated in first column and second column. `YYVTIIDAPGHR` is repetaed in first column and second column . etc etc

And then give me a percentage first column has 8 rows, among these 8 rows, it shares 2 rows with column 2 so it has 2/8*100 = 25% share 
first with third share 3/8*100 = 37%
column 2 with column 3 shares 0% 
etc etc

Comment: Based on your posted dataset columns 1 and 3 share 4 rows and not 3. They share FPEHELIVDPQR twice, DLNYCFSGMSDHR and DLNYCFSGMSDHR. 
Also in your first desired output you have "DLNYCFSGMSDHR   1,3" twice and it's not good to have duplicates. I tried to solve those issues in my solution below.

Comment: Your percentages are not clear. Please update with expected output

Comment: @Sotos thanks for your message. Let say we have 8 strings in the first column. and 2 of those are shared with second column, so the percentage of column A sharing to colum B is 2/8*100. is this clear now?

Comment: I think it important to understand what happens with strings that appear multiple times in a column. Are you planning to work with number of rows or number of unique strings that match? For example DLNYCFSGMSDHR in column V3 should count as one or as two matches with V1?

Comment: @AntoniosK replicate should count as 2 matches (but please tell me if you can also give me a unique solution too)

Comment: This is possible, but it will affect the number of rows as well if we assume we want to exclude duplicates. That means that V1 will have 7 rows and V3 4. It depends on what you want to achieve by this process.

Comment: @AntoniosK Yes, definelty  , two solutions will be great

Comment: The Venn diagram will not work with row matching, but with unique strings matching. Because V1 matches 4 times with V3 and V3 2 times with V1. I'd suggest to remove duplicates before you proceed to the matching.

Comment: @AntoniosK sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really feel that number of common stings after removing duplicates for each row (i.e considering unique strings that match) is more useful. So, I'm updating my solution and I'm adding some more code to get the Venn diagram.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gplots)

# reshape dataset
df_reshaped = df %>% 
  gather(column, string) %>% 
  filter(string != '') %>%
  distinct()

# dataset that shows all strings and in which columns they appear
df_result1 = df_reshaped %>% 
  group_by(string) %>% 
  summarise(columns = paste(unique(column), collapse=","))

df_result1


# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#                        string columns
#                         <chr>   <chr>
# 1           AVCMLSNTTAIAEAWAR      V3
# 2           CPSIAAAIAAVNALHGR   V1,V2
# 3               DLNYCFSGMSDHR   V1,V3
# 4                FPEHELIVDPQR   V1,V3
# 5           GCITIIGGGDTATCCAK      V2
# 6 HVGPGVLSMANAGPNTNGSQFFICTIK      V2
# 7         IADPDAVKPDDWDEDAPSK      V1
# 8             LLELGPKPEVAQQTR      V2
# 9               LWADHGVQACFGR      V1
# 10     MVCCSAWSEDHPICNLFTCGFDR     V2
# 11       WGEAGAEYVVESTGVFTTMEK     V1
# 12                YYVTIIDAPGHR  V1,V2


# function to get number of common rows
f1 = function(v1, v2) {
  x1 = (df_reshaped %>% filter(column == v1))$string
  x2 = (df_reshaped %>% filter(column == v2))$string
  length(x2[x2 %in% x1]) }
f1 = Vectorize(f1)


# function to get number of rows of each column
f2 = function(v) {df_reshaped %>% filter(column == v) %>% nrow}
f2 = Vectorize(f2)

# dataset that shows overlap of columns (number of common strings)
expand.grid(unique(df_reshaped$column), unique(df_reshaped$column)) %>%
  filter(Var1 != Var2) %>%
  mutate(NumShared = f1(Var1, Var2),
         NumRows = f2(Var1),
         Prc = NumShared/NumRows) %>%
  arrange(Var1, Var2)

#   Var1 Var2 NumShared NumRows       Prc
# 1   V1   V2         2       7 0.2857143
# 2   V1   V3         2       7 0.2857143
# 3   V2   V1         2       6 0.3333333
# 4   V2   V3         0       6 0.0000000
# 5   V3   V1         2       3 0.6666667
# 6   V3   V2         0       3 0.0000000


# reshape dataset and create a Venn diagram
df_reshaped %>%
  mutate(exist = TRUE) %>%
  spread(column, exist, fill=FALSE) %>%
  select(-string) %>%
  venn()
```

The Venn diagram looks like:
[image]

Obviously, the sum of the numbers shown in this diagram should be equal to the number of unique strings you get in the table `df_result1`. Which is 12 in our case.

Comment: this is if we have only 3 columns, what if we have many columns and their names are not V?

Comment: You have to replace `V1:V3` in the `gather` command with the names of your columns, in a similar way. The rest should remain the same as the code will recognise how many columns you have, what names to use and how many pairs of columns to check for shared rows.

Comment: for example, can I do this c(col1,col2,col3,col10,col50) ?  also would it be possible to help me making a plot from it? I will like and accept your answer

Comment: Yes you can use something like that within the `gather` command. You can do `gather(column, string, col1,col2,col3,col10,col50)`. That way if you have any other columns they won't be considered here.
What kind of plot do you want to create?

Comment: I don't think you need to go through all that trouble. Something like `df %>% gather(var, string) %>% filter(string != '') %>% group_by(string) %>% summarise(common = toString(unique(var)))` should be enough

Comment: @AntoniosK  venn diagram or something similar if you know any

Comment: @Sotos what do you suggest ? can you also give your solution? at least I will like it :-)

Comment: I've updated my solution based on @Sotos suggestion. Which is no need to specify the names of the columns within the `gather` comand. The process will pick them automatically. However, this assumes you don't have any extra/unnecessary columns as well.

Comment: @AntoniosK thanks, can you add a figure too ? I will accept it. I already liked your answer

Comment: @AntoniosK the venn diagram is not supported for more than 6 columns?

Comment: Hmmm, I have no idea. That would be a big limitation I guess. Try to leave more space for the plot (make the window bigger) and it might work. Do you get a specific error?